Finding the area of triangle $ABC$, if $BC=8$ and $2\sin{A}+3\cos{B}\cos{C}=4$

In the $\triangle ABC$, $BC=8$, $2\sin{A}+3\cos{B}\cos{C}=4$. How to find the area of $\triangle ABC$?

I use
$$-\cos{A}=\cos{(B+C)}=\cos{B}\cos{C}-\sin{B}\sin{C} \tag1$$
So I got
$$2\sin{A}-3\cos{A}+3\sin{B}\sin{C}=4 \tag2$$
I have a smack at use
$$4=\frac{a}{2} \quad\text{and}\quad \sin{A}=\frac{a}{2R} \tag3$$
to get the edge relationship, but I can't get the result.
How can I solve it?

Please post a picture of this.

@Nate There is no graph for this problem.

It is helpful to remove the angle $A$ in the angle equation, so writing $\sin A = \sin(B+C)$, we have
$$2\sin(B+C)+ 3\cos B \cos C = 4.$$
To now do something with the other term, we use the identity
$$\cos (B+C) +\cos(B-C)=2\cos B \cos C$$
to get $$2\sin(B+C)+ \frac{3}{2}(\cos (B+C) +\cos(B-C)) = 4$$
so $$4\sin(B+C)+ 3\cos (B+C) +3\cos(B-C) = 8$$
Now note the maximum value of $4\sin(B+C)+ 3\cos (B+C)$ is 5 and the maximum value of $3\cos(B-C)$ is 3.
Thus for this equation to hold we must have $4\sin(B+C)+ 3\cos (B+C)=5$ and
$3\cos(B-C)=3$.
Thus $B=C$ and and $4\sin(2B)+ 3\cos (2B)=5$.
We can now either find B numerically or use the identities
$$\sin(2B)= \dfrac{2\tan B}{1+\tan^2 B}\ \ \ \cos(2B)= \dfrac{1-\tan^2 B}{1+\tan^2 B}$$
to show that $\tan B = \frac{1}{2}$.
Can you finish from here?

Because of $4\sin{(B+C)}+3\cos{(B+C)}+3\cos{(B-C)}=8$, I can get $B-C=0$, use $\tan{B}=\frac{1}{2}$, I can get $\tan{A}=-\tan{(B+C)}=-\tan{2B}=-\frac{4}{3}, so \sin{A}=\frac{4}{5}, R=\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=5, \sin{B}=\sin{C}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$, so the area is $2R^2\cdot \sin{A}\cdot \sin{B}\cdot \sin{C}=\frac{8R^2}{25}=8$

Yes. Alternatively, think of the triangle as two isosceles triangles with base 4 and height $4\tan B = 2$. Then area is $2\times \frac{1}{2}\times 4 \times 2=8$.
